# What version of "mysql-connector-java" be use for Spring sts release 3.2.3?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Am using sts release version 3.2.3.for jdbc connection, i have given the dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>mysql</groupId>
  <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
  <version>5.1.6</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
```

Its throwing error:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.needsRefresh(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/InjectionMetadata;Ljava/lang/Class;)Z

Some jar files i have used seems to be mismatch .
Can somebody please guide me  which version of "mysql-connector-java" be used for spring 3.2.3 release ?? And how to know which version of jars i should used??
Thanks

Comment: The error isn't related to the mysql driver but  by mixing different versions of spring.

Answer (score 1):

The `needsRefresh`  method was added in `spring 4.0.x` and it can't be found in the `3.0.x` version.